# Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?)

Tags: php, forms, laravel-8

I'm having this problem with Laravel:

**Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?)**

To try to resolve the error I have enabled the following line in the php.ini file

*extension=fileinfo*

but the error still persists.

This is the code:

```js
<form method="POST" action="{{route('article.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{old('title')}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="file" name="img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <textarea name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10">{{old('description')}}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

**Controller:**

```js
public function store(ArticleRequest $req){

        
        $article = Article::create([
            'title'=>$req->title,
            'description'=>$req->description,
            'img'=>$req->file('img')->store('public/img')
        ]);
        //dd($article);
        return redirect(route('homepage'));
    }
```

Comment: Just to ask, have you restarted the PHP process?

Comment: @ChrisHaas How do you do this? I'm new

Comment: I depends on the server, do you know what you are using? Here's some answers: https://serverfault.com/q/189940

Comment: @ChrisHaas Perfect, the problem was just restarting the server. Unfortunately I am new and I have to learn several things

Comment: No worries! We all started somewhere!